# WeChat iOS SDK Sharing - missing description despite filling parameter

Tags: ios, sdk, share, wechat

When I try to send link or picture with `description` paremeter to **WeChatMoments** or **WeChatSession**, description is never shown. Every other parameter is shown correctly, except description.  There are no errors either. Here goes my code, notice that `description` is filled:

```
    WXMediaMessage *message = [WXMediaMessage message];
    message.title = @"Perfect Title";
    message.description = @"Amazing Graphic";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:thumbnailPath]];
    [message setThumbImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];

    WXImageObject *ext = [WXImageObject object];
    NSString* filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:contentPath]];
    ext.imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] ;

    message.mediaObject = ext;

    SendMessageToWXReq* req = [[[SendMessageToWXReq alloc] init]autorelease];
    req.bText = NO;
    req.message = message;
    req.scene = (true)?WXSceneTimeline:WXSceneSession;

    [WXApi sendReq:req];
```

I've tried code samples from [WeChatDeveloper documentation](http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/messages-moments), and even despite of filling `description` paremeter, it does only show link with title/graphic.

My question is, anybody faced same problem and there is any solution for missing description field?

May problem occur because my app is not yet verified?